# CSS: z-index not working on SPAN in Google Chrome

Tags: gwt, dom, css, styles

This is part of the DOM of a GWT app. The `<span>` represents an arrow, and the `<div>` that is just below represents a square. The code is repeated, so this is drawing correctly:
**ARROW1 SQUARE1 ARROW2 SQUARE2**

`Square1` has a scaling style, so it is actually bigger than `Square2`, and should overlap Arrow2. This is the issue: `Square1` should be displayed OVER `Arrow2` (that is why its `z-index:1` and `Arrow2`' `z-index:0`). However, it is the other way round: **Arrow2 is displayed OVER Square1**.

This is happening in Google Chrome, but in IE9 works fine. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
<div style="width:489PX;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
  <div style="cursor:pointer;">
    <div id="p379ehovd03-1" style="z-index=1;">
      /***** ARROW 1 BELOW *****/
      <span id="p21023d9223" style="z-index=1;"></span> 
      /***** SQUARE 1 BELOW *****/
      <div id="qu39rtgh93he-1" style="width:126PX;height:100PX;z-index=1;-moz-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);-webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);-o-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);-ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);transform: scale(1.1, 1.1); -moz-transform-origin: center center;-webkit-transform-origin: center center;-o-transform-origin: center center;-ms-transform-origin: center center;transform-origin: center center;z-index: 1">
        <p>adsfadsfasdfa</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="cursor:pointer;z-index:0;">
    <div id="p379ehovd03-2" style="z-index:0;">
      /***** ARROW 2 BELOW *****/
      <span id="p2782bhsd29" style="display:block;z-index:0;"></span>
      /***** SQUARE 2 BELOW *****/
      <div id="qu39rtgh93he-2" style="width:126PX;height:100PX;"> 
        <p>adsfadsf</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add position: relative to the span tag, that should do it (I think)

Comment: All elements that have a z-index have to have a position on them, whether that be absolute, relative, etc.

Comment: Actually it worked with position: absolute on the DIV of Square1!!

Comment: Great! This is just one of those things that needs remembering ;)

Comment: Also, it's generally best to use an external stylesheet instead of using inline styles like above (you may already know this, just wanted to check)

Comment: Yeah, actually I have this on an external css. This is just a test on the DOM recreating the issue. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It worked adding **position: absolute** on the DIV of Square1.

Answer (score 4):

Adding position will work whether is absolute or relative

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the span element:

```
display:block;
```